# Android studio doesn't draw button correctly

Tags: android, button, constraints, draw, shift

In my Android studio project I have a fragment with constraint layout inside. Here is XML.

```
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/pinLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topLayout">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/numberTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:text="00000000"
                    android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_shape_tint"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:text="Confirm Pin"
                    android:textColor="@color/appMainColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pinView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                        android:textSize="36sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pinView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                        android:textSize="36sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pinView3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                        android:textSize="36sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pinView4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see the confirm button is centered with constraints in his parent.

[image]

But when I am running application in my Xperia z5 compact, a layout inspector shows that button is not centered.

[image]

Why does it happen and how to fix that?

**Note** if I am removing numberTextView with it's parent constarintLayout, the problem disappears.
**Note** In my code I am programmatically setting a text to numberTextView. In case when I am commenting that code i.e not setting text programmatically, button draws correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the below line from your button layout in xml.

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
```

Horizontal Bias:
This allows us to position a view along the horizontal axis using a bias value, this will be relative to it’s constrained position.

For more information about Constraint Layout refer
[this article](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1)

Comment: Doesn't help me. The button is not centered vertically. How can horizontal bias constraint affect on vertical position?

Comment: Also remove the  " app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4" " from the parent constraint layout of the button. Also there is no need to give constraint layout as parent to each view. Refer the article above to learn more on ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 1):

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
```

`layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` this will make a small variation from center. try code given below,

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_shape_tint"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:text="Confirm Pin"
                android:textColor="@color/appMainColor"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Doesn't help me. The button is not centered vertically. How can horizontal bias constraint affect on vertical position?

Comment: the problem is, position of button that you declared is not correct. declare the button outside 2nd ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 1):

`android:id="@+id/pinLayout"` has hight of `250dp` that's why button doesn't position at vertically center. try the code given below.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/pinLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cl_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:text="00000000"
                android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_root"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pinView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                    android:textSize="36sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pinView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                    android:textSize="36sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pinView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                    android:textSize="36sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pinView4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                    android:textSize="36sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_shape_tint"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="Confirm Pin"
            android:textColor="@color/appMainColor"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: because of setting constraintLayout2's height to match parent, it covers whole parent view.

Answer (score 0):

try to use RelativeLayout instead of ConstraintLayout by changing all ConstraintLayout to RelativeLayout in your xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout >
...
Your content
...
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout >
...
Your content
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

then you might give set your button to be center in parent

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

for your TextView pinView1, pinView2, pinView3 and pinView4 you have simply put it inside a LinearLayout.