# Android studio doesn't draw button correctly, shifts down

Tags: android, button, constraints, draw

In my Android studio project I have a fragment with constraint layout inside. Here is XML.

```
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/pinLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topLayout">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/numberTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:text="00000000"
                    android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_shape_tint"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:text="Confirm Pin"
                    android:textColor="@color/appMainColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pinView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                        android:textSize="36sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pinView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                        android:textSize="36sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pinView3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                        android:textSize="36sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pinView4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/appTintColor"
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see the confirm button is centered with constraints in his parent.

[image]

But when I am running application in my Xperia z5 compact, a layout inspector shows that button is not centered.

[image]

Why does it happen and how to fix that?

**Note** if I am removing numberTextView with it's parent constarintLayout, the problem disappears.
**Note** In my code I am programmatically setting a text to numberTextView. In case when I am commenting that code i.e not setting text programmatically, button draws correctly.

Here is code part, where I am setting text to NumberTextView

```
private void performInitialLayout() {
    fragmentViewHeight = fragmentView.getHeight();

    ViewRelatedUtils.setHeightPercentage(topView, scrollView, 0.3);
    ViewRelatedUtils.setHeightPercentage(pinLayout, scrollView, 0.4);

    // here I am setting a text.
    numberTextView.setText(number);

    if (isProcessingPinConfirmation) showProcessing(); else hideProcessing();

    wrapperView.requestFocus();

    performedInitialLayout = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the picture what do you want to achieve, because it can be completed with single constraint layout

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh as you can see in the second picture, layout inspector shows that the button is not vertically centered in his parent, despite to constraints, and it happens in case when I am programmatically setting a text to NumberTextView. I want the button and numberTextView to be right in the center of their's parents after setting text to nuberTextView.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio doesn't draw button correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931441/android-studio-doesnt-draw-button-correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read my comment on the question, although I have made some changes to your layout, check this out

Change the colors as per your requirement.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout17"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/hint_color">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="00000000"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_button"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:text="Confirm Pin"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pinView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pinView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pinView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pinView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_color"
                android:textSize="36sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want constant margins like 60dp, I want all to be proportional as much as possible.

Comment: Then please post a picture what do you desire, otherwise, with words, I can't understand you, although I have updated the answer

Comment: Check my updated answer, I have made changes in your layout file

Comment: Doesn't help, I think there is something than we haven't an idea about, because the problem occurs when I am programmatically setting text to the numberTextView.

Comment: I have updated question and added part of code where I am setting text to numberTextView. Is it important to set @+id/linearLayout17's height to match_parent?

Comment: setting pinLayout's height to match_parent solved the problem, but now my layout builder looks not well.